# Get the value from the n-1 node with lxml.etree

Tags: python, lxml

I have this etree:

```
<root>
  <test>
    <criteria nom="DR">
        <abbr>DR</abbr>
        <value>0.123456</value>
    </criteria>
    <criteria nom="MOTA">
        <abbr>MOTA</abbr>
        <value>0.132465</value>
    </criteria>
    <criteria nom="PFR">
        <abbr>PFR</abbr>
        <value>0.914375</value>
    </criteria>
  </test>
  <test>
    <criteria nom="DR">
        <abbr>DR</abbr>
        <value>0.655425</value>
    </criteria>
    <criteria nom="MOTA">
        <abbr>MOTA</abbr>
        <value>0.766545</value>
    </criteria>
    <criteria nom="PFR">
        <abbr>PFR</abbr>
        <value>0.943154</value>
    </criteria>
  </test>
</root>
```

and I need to get one by one the values

```
0.655425
0.766545
0.943154
```

to be able to compare them to the value "0.25".

--EDIT--

I already tried to get the values by looping in the main tree like this:

```
tree = etree.fromstring(the tree above)
root = tree.getroot()
for test in root.findall("test"):
  for criteria in test.findall(criteria):
    value = criteria.findall("value").text()
```

but this does not work.

Comment: I know you asked for a `lxml.etree` solution, but, you could also use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). It's pretty easy to use.

Comment: Did you try something yourself?

Comment: @KeyurPotdar it would effectively be easier but I can't use non-native python libs

Comment: @CristiFati I did, by looping in the element tree, but what I need is in fact to select the last test mark and loop from there - i'm going to correct this

Comment: Should I take your word for it? Just kidding. Check [\[SO\]: How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more asking related details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **xml module**. and use `enumerate`.

**Ex**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring(s)
for i, content in enumerate(tree.findall(".//test")):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        for val in content.findall("criteria/value"):
            print(val.text)
```

**Output:**

```
0.655425
0.766545
0.943154
```

Comment: okay!
One more question, how do I select only
``` 
0.655425
0.766545
0.943154
``` from the values?

Comment: Updated snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Use [lxml and XPath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath):

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse(open("so.xml"))
for value in tree.xpath("/root/test[2]/criteria/value"):
    print(value.text)
```